# removeAtIndex with didSet

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, properties

We have a class with an array property that has a `didSet` observer. However, it seems that when we call `removeAtIndex` on this array, the `didSet` observer is called. Is there any way we can stop this from happening?

```
var items: [String] = []
{
    didSet
    {
        println(self.items.count)
    }
}
...
func removeIndex(index: Int)
{
    self.items.removeAtIndex(index)
    // now didSet is called, but we don't want that
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The didSet method will be called automatically, if you do not want to execute the lines of code in didSet method, the below tricks may work for you.

1. Take `Bool` variable, and in the willSet observer method make it to true, in didSet method check for this bool variable's status and if true ignore, and immediately make that to false.
2. In didSet observer method you will get the oldValue of the array and find the count, and compare with current count.

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for, but thanks. Any idea why calling `removeAtIndex` causes `didSet` to be called? I would think that `didSet` would only be called when I reassign the property, like `self.items = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty unexpected.

For my case, I was able to maintain an index variable that I advance, instead of pulling items out of the array.